# PEP 8 - Module name vs variable name for instance

Tags: python, naming, pep8

Suppose I have a Python module `my_class.py` ([see PEP 8 convention for modules](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names)) that holds a class `MyClass` ([see PEP 8 convention for classes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)).

Now I want to instantiate that class in a module in the same package and would normally do

```
from .my_class import MyClass
my_class = MyClass()
```

since PEP 8 proposes this naming scheme for instance variable names [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names).

However, in this context, `my_class` already refers to the module `my_class.py` and the instance variable would therefore shadow the module.

Do PEP 8 or any other sources give any direction on how to proceed here, or is it just up to the developer to think of a different but less intuitive name for the variable?

Comment: Since instantiated `class` represents an `instance` (rather than "just a class"), the  appropriate thing to write would be `my_instance = MyClass()`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Smuuf calling it `MyClass` is just an example, in a real useacase the class might not be called `MyClass` but e. g. `JsonParser`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, you have explicitly imported `MyClass`.

While the module `my_class` is imported it will not be assigned a variable in your local scope and hence you will not be shadowing it by using `my_class` for your `MyClass` instance.

**Update**

When importing a module within the same package it looks like a reference is added to the local scope, however, there is no risk in using the same name. Variables in Python are references to an object rather than the object.

When you reassign a reference (eg use the name for another object) the object is deleted *if there are no other references* to the object. In the case of modules they are added to `sys.modules` when imported, in which case there is always another reference and they are not deleted.

Comment: Thank you! Why is it then that I still don't get an error if I do `a = my_class` (without doing `my_class = MyClass()` aka without defining a local variable called `my_class`? In my understanding, this is because `my_class` is a reference to the module that would be shadowed if I defined a variable of the same name... Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @TobiasFeil You _will_ get an error if you simply do `from .my_class import MyClass; a = my_class`.

Comment: Also, use `print(my_class)` to see what it holds. E.g. for me `print(os)` (after importing it) is `<module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py'>`

Comment: @L3viathan Sorry, I should have said that I'm doing so in my package's `__init__.py`, because I'm not getting an error there.

Comment: Also, if I print `my_class`, like h4z3 suggested, it prints precisely that - it tells me it's a module defined in the filename where I defined it.

Comment: Looking closer at this it's likely related to how modules within the same package are imported. However, it looks like a side effect and I would not rely on this behaviour. Unless you are explicitly importing an item (or the name is a builtin) you can safely use the name for a variable, there is no risk in doing so.

Comment: Thank you. I hope so as well, it seems quite weird to me that PyCharm is giving me a warning about shadowing as well. I guess I'll just give it a different name for now... Don't wanna switch off the warning

Comment: So if I do `from .my_class import MyClass` or even just `from .my_class import pd` (assuming pandas is imported in `my_class.py`) at the beginning of the code, then `my_class` is defined (and points to the respective module). If I don't import anything, `my_class` isn't defined either.

Comment: @TobiasFeil That's correct like I said in the answer variables in Python are references to an object. When doing an import you get a new local variable referencing the imported object. You can technically import any local variable in a module including other imported items, functions, constants etc